# How to keep the DIVs below from sliding up when hovering over a DIV

Tags: css, html, hover

I am having some trouble when I hover over a DIV, the DIVs underneath slide up underneath the DIV I'm hovering over. How can Is top them from doing this?

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcTHf/) to illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inadvertently solved this problem while trying to fix another one:

I changed this:

`.calendar-event:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FAFAFA;
    border: solid 1px #999999;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}`

to this:

`.calendar-event:hover .event-title {
    overflow: visible;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FAFAFA;
    border: solid 1px #999999;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}`

And it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS:

```
.calendar-event:hover {
    overflow: visible;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FAFAFA;
    border: solid 1px #999999;
    width: auto;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

The problem is the last property. Remove the "position: absolute;"; this is causing the div to escape from the browser's normal positioning flow.

Comment: I would do that, but I think I need to keep it so that the hover element stays above everything else on the page.